# Не приходят запросы на порт 993

Tags: debian, email, postfix, dovecot

Я НЕ системный администратор, но так уж вышло, что надо настроить почтовый сервер.
По большому счёту, более чем уверен что postfix + dovecot настроил правильно.

Проблема заключается лишь в том, что при подключении с почтового клиента, тишина на порту 993.

Т.е. настроил клиент на порт 143 - tcpdump показывает запросы
Переключаюсь в клиенте на 993 - в tcpdump тишина, в клиенте ошибка.

Клиенты: gmail, outlook, thunderbird
Server OS: Debian
Порты открыты в iptable и в ufw

Comment: А кто и как конкретно настроен принимать подключения на порту 993? Не забыли прописать его в настройках dovecot или типа того?

Comment: Да. Прописал. Так а в любом случае, разве есть разница? Прописал он или нет в софте, если tcpdump должен видеть любые запросы на порт, независимо от софта